# CSS3 rotation transform

Tags: css

Given the following Fiddle, how can I make the red rectangle stand upright in the vertical plane?

http://jsfiddle.net/paulsidebottom/vEWEL/

I've tried altering the rotation transform for the marker but it seems to rotate about the same axis.

```
    #marker
    {   
      -webkit-transform:rotateY(-50deg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preserve the 3d transformations on its parent:

```
    .threeD
    {
         -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         -webkit-transform: rotateX(55deg);
         -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
         position:relative;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I also had to remove -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; from container element (I've updated the Fiddle).